# What happened to Shaidar Haran, the super Myrddraal (minor spoiler)?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Shaidar Haran does not seem to show up at the Last Battle.  What is his fate?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rand encounters Shaidar Haran soon after he enters Shayol Ghul.

> The figure stood and turned, Moridin's now familiar face reflecting
>  Callandor's glow. Beside him on the ground lay a husk. Rand could
>  explain it no other way. It was like the shell some instects leave
>  behind when they grow only it was in the shape of a man. A Man with no
>  eyes. One of the Myrddraal?
>  
>  Moridin looked to the husk, following Rand's gaze. "A vessel my master
>  needed no longer," Moridin said. Saa floated in the whites of his eye,
>  bouncing, shaking, moving with crazed vigor. "It gave birth to what is
>  behind me."
>  
>  "There is nothing behind you."
>  
>  Moridin raised his sword before his face in a salute. "Exactly."

<sub>A Memory of Light, Chapter 25 - *Quick Fragments*</sub>